# Visual Studio 2019 - Angular 8 - Timeout Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2019, angular8, timeoutexception

I'm using the following:

Windows 10 64 Bit

Visual Studio 2019 Community (16.3.3)

1. Create New Project
2. ASP.NET Core Web Application
3. .NET Core / ASP.NET Core 3.0
4. Select the Angular template
5. Create
6. From package.json in the ClientApp folder, the Angular version is 8.0.0
7. Rebuild
8. Wait
9. Start Without Debugging - works great!!!
10. Start Debugging - TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
11. Browser refresh does not solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use Visual Studio for back-end (ASP.NET Core) and VS Code for front-end (Angular) of Web Application.

1. You can open the Angular front-end app folder in VS Code after
   creating the project in Visual Studio with Angular template.
2. Install angular-cli globally and other required packages from VS
       Code Terminal.
3. Install the desired Angular extensions for better development
   experience.
4. Configure Debugging in VS Code for your default Browser.